# Doubt about short circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, short-circuits

[image]

I have been asked to find the equivalent resistance in the following circuit. However, is the circuit valid, as a zero resistance wire is connected between 2 different potentials?

Also, how to calculate the net resistance here?

Comment: (a) "a zero resistance wire is connected between 2 different potentials" The zero resistance wire ensures that the points it joins are at the same potential! (b) Try redrawing the circuit; you'll see that it's pretty simple.

Comment: @PhilipWood Yes, but how does the potential increase in between, without a battery?

Comment: It won't increase; you do need a battery. But you can calculate the resistance between A and B without imagining a battery to be in place.

Comment: @PhilipWood I am at a loss here. The first resistance certainly causes a potential drop, yet after adding another resistance, the potential somehow jumps to the previous level. Can you please explain this in more detail?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/643252/2451

Comment: My advice is (a) Don't concern yourself with potentials. (b) REDRAW THE CIRCUIT! Hint: One end of each of the left hand resistor and the middle resistor connect to point A.

Comment: Consider that if the first and third resistors have very high resistance values, current flows across the top wire, through the second resistor *from right to left*, and then across the bottom wire. We don't necessarily have the voltage dropping at every node from left to right, current may not be flowing in the direction you expect.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Thanks, got it!

Comment: Did you come to see that the three resistors are connected in parallel between points A and B?

Comment: @PhilipWood Yup!