To find the equivalent resistance between points A and B in the circuit

The question is to find equivalent resistance between A and B. My teacher solved it by marking equipotential points and modifying the circuit as shown below

Clearly, as per the modified circuit, the three resistances are connected in parallel between A and B and equivalent resistance becomes R/3.
But I tried to solve it like this:

Initially a current "i" passing through point A should completely flow through the short wire (the wire with no resistance in the diagram), and thus current only encounters one resistor on the way, making equivalent resistance equal to R. What's wrong here?
Im a high school student so a simple yet convincing answer is expected.. Also, i am not comfortable with the method of modifying(or redrawing) of the circuit. It's just not convincing enough to me. So, I'd like to know another method(if it exists) to solve this problem.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/643252/2451 and links therein.
